# python.exe is not a valid win32 application error coming suddenly

Tags: python, windows

My python environment was working alright before and after running a C++ code multiple times from python subprocesses, I started the computer and saw that it says that python.exe is not a valid win32 application and I no longer access python. What changed I am not sure. Will I need to reinstall python? When I open the IDE, this message comes Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Probably, yes.  It's hard to say anything more without knowing anything about what you did.

Comment: I suddenly have the same problem. Did you solve it somehow?

Comment: When you install python, make sure that python path option is checked. It is unchecked by default.

Answer (score 2):

Download (or open if you already have) dependency walker, then open python.exe in it. See if you are missing a DLL or got a DLL corrupted. You may require to re-install python, some reference DLL or exe files could be corrupted/overwritten/modified/deleted.

Comment: Which dependency walker do you recommend?