# Error when trying to run python 3 (python.exe is not a valid win32 application)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have python 3.3 on my Desktop and works perfectly fine. I'm trying to install 3.5 on my main laptop I work from, but once it is "successfully installed" (the message the installer always gives me) It doesn't want to open. I get a message saying python.exe is not a valid win32 application. My OS is windows vista.
[image: SS of dependency walker]

Comment: There are way to many moving parts here for anyone to help you solve the problem, particularly with the hand-waving (*"or something like that"*?)

Comment: Anything here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168522/python-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-error-coming-suddenly or here? https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2071/

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist They didn't really help

Comment: 64-bit executable on 32-bit Windows?

Comment: Agreed with dsh, ensure the bitness of the installation. 64 bit python installation for 64 bit machine only

Comment: @Busturdust It says `Python 3.5.0 (32-bit) Setup`

Comment: @dsh It says Python 3.5.0 (32-bit) Setup

Comment: The installer should have installed the new Universal C Runtime (`ucrtbase.dll`) and API set DLLs (`api-ms-win-crt-*.dll`). On Vista and Windows 7 I think the API set DLLs exist as real files. (OTOH, I know in Windows 10 they're just API sets, not actual files.) Are these DLLs present in either of the `System32` or `SysWOW64` system directories in the Windows directory (typically `C:\Windows`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that that version of python won't work on your specific version of windows. You are going to have to use python 3.4 as this is the only python 3 version that will work for your os.

Answer (score 1):

Go http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and download depends.exe. Run depends.exe and open python exe. If you are lucky it will show you missing dependencies.

Check how to install these. Or post missing dependencies in your question. Maybe someone knows which package to install.

EDIT:
Watch for yellow exclamation/question marks!

EDIT:
Based on eryksun's comment you should install the Vista package from this site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226

Comment: This is what that download gave me `Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.`

Comment: look at the screenshot on the end of depends homepage. your depends shows you what .dll-file is missing. get the missing files and your python will run! the missing files are usually parts of a package, for example .net framework 4.5 (idk if it is necessary, just an example)

Comment: I posted a ss in my question